# Try Catch block not catching exception in QCompleter for pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a qcompleter setup so that it fills in two different lineEdits when a suggestion is highlighted. When the user uses the arrows to iterate through the suggestions and goes out of bounds, an index error gets raised. For example, if the completer gives one suggestion but the user hits the down arrow twice, then the selected suggestion goes out of bounds and raises the exception. The bug is that I have it surrounded by a try except block but it's not catching the exception for whatever reason. Is it possible to force the highlighted selection to start from index 0 when the user tries to go out of bounds?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCompleter


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def on_button(self, text):
        try:
            nameList = text.split(', ')
            self.lineEdit_2.setText(nameList[0])
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda: self.lineEdit.setText(nameList[1]))

        except IndexError:
            print("Out of bounds")

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(439, 254)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 90, 180, 25))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 90, 180, 25))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")

        food = ["pizza, chikin", "chikin, pizza", "chikin, pizza pizza", "chikin, pizza", "fried, pizza"]

        completer = QCompleter(food)
        completer.setCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        completer.setFilterMode(QtCore.Qt.MatchContains)
        self.lineEdit.setCompleter(completer)

        try:

            completer.highlighted.connect(self.on_button)
            completer.activated.connect(self.on_button)

        except IndexError:
            print("Out of bounds")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack.py", line 13, in 
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda: self.lineEdit.setText(nameList[1]))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: what is the Traceback when it happens?

Comment: Just included it as an edit under the code

Comment: python version?

Comment: version - Python 3.6.7

Comment: Are you sure everything reloaded properly? The try/except looks fine, so first thing would be to make sure the app is killed properly before testing it again.

Comment: how do you test the app. @h4z3 is right, you are catching the correct exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main incomprehension is that in `try ... except` block you have connecting functions to signals. Not executing them.

Solution which saving the timer usage:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCompleter


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def on_button(self, text):
        if text not in self.food:
            self.lineEdit_2.setText("")
            return
        nameList = text.split(', ')
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(nameList[0])
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda: self.lineEdit.setText(nameList[1]))


    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(439, 254)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 90, 180, 25))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 90, 180, 25))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")

        self.food = ["pizza, chikin", "chikin, pizza", "chikin, pizza pizza", "chikin, pizza", "fried, pizza"]

        completer = QCompleter(self.food)
        completer.setCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        completer.setFilterMode(QtCore.Qt.MatchContains)
        self.lineEdit.setCompleter(completer)

        try:

            completer.highlighted.connect(self.on_button)
            # completer.activated.connect(self.on_button)

        except IndexError:
            print("Out of bounds")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

I just run your code and don't understand why do you have to change the value of lineEdit inside the QTimer. I just did this

```
self.lineEdit.setText(nameList[1])
```

and the suggestion and the catching of the IndexError: works as I understand you intended it to do it.It is posible that the error comes from calling inside the QTimer. Maybe you have a reason for the QTimer but it is not clear to me.

Comment: I use the timer because if you don't then the user has to hit enter an extra time to have the first lineEdit fill in with the first word. When they hit enter on "fried, pizza" the first lineEdit will still say "fried, pizza" unless they hit enter an extra time. You can test it yourself to see what I'm talking about

Answer (score 0):

If im not mistaken, OP uses

```
QtCore.QTimer.singleShot
```

so to create a timer event to switch the list index back to 0 once the text is set in index 1.

Try simply setting the text

```
self.lineEdit.setText(nameList[1])
```

And then use your except block to call a function which will reselect the index 0 in nameList.

The error in exception handling probably has something to do with the active run time of the timer event - though im unsure.